# Can we do 302 redirect with javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect

Or does it have to be server side?

Currently google requires all sites to 302 to a page rather than the usual pages.

How do I do so with javascript? Can I just print a 302 code in meta or something?

Note: sorry. This is not google for search engine. This is google the feed provider for bodis.com above.com namedrive.com and a bunch of other guy.

I am a domain parker. I get domains ranked at search engine and move traffic somewhere else. The problem is google now prohibit URL forwarding. I am just thinking how do I maintain my ranking with more transparent forwarding such as 302. The destination URL is pretty, I would say blank.

Comment: Seeing as how you're talking about Google, is this SEO related?

Comment: @bdares I think so, 302 is needed if you want to get the same pr of the redirected domain.

Comment: On a side note: Why did you want to do this with javascript? Can't you use PHP?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is how a 302 redirect works:

`HTTP 302` means found. In a way, the server tells the client where to retrieve the page it requested.

**Example:**

The client sends:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yourdomain.com
```

The server responds:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http:/yoursubdomain.someotherdomain.com/somefolder
```

This is why you couldn't achieve a 302 redirect using javascript. It's part of the HTTP protocol. No page gets loaded by the client's browser before the redirect is performed.

Comment: Very very well explained. It's so difficult to find this info on the net. +1