# Track 302 temporary redirects on host domain

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics

I have domain X, and I want to do a **302 Temporary Redirect** to domain Z.
I also want to keep track (with Google Analytics?) of all the visitors hitting domain X and being redirected to domain Z.

Currently, I don't have access to domain Z, so I can't use the referrer to track the incoming visitors from domain X.

Is there a way I can achieve that using Google Analytics?

- If so, should I code this redirect in a certain way?
- Otherwise, is there an Analytics alternative that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Google Analytics you'll need a javascript redirect (since GA is basically Javascript and needs a html page as "host").

It would be possible to construct a server side script that sends data to GA before doing a redirect (using something like http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/), only it wouldn't be worth the trouble - you won't learn anything useful in analytics from a redirect page, so a simple counter would be more  than enough.

Comment: It seems that [it's not possible to do a 302 redirect using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7658373/341929).

Comment: That's what I was trying to say. Sorry for expressing myself not more clearly.