# Not able to perform redirect 302

Tags: javascript

I am trying to redirect using javascript to another page ( not on same origin ) but the code that the other website is getting is 200 redirect , we are trying to perform 302 redirect using Javascript

Using the following code -

```
     <script>top.location = "https://example.com";</script>
```

How can I perform 302 redirect using Javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the code that the other website is getting*"? All the redirect target website gets is a *request*.

Comment: It was answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658199/can-we-do-302-redirect-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

A 302 redirect using Javascript should not be possible. It's part of the HTTP protocol. After the client sends the request to the server, the server responds with a redirect. No page is ever loaded by the Browser.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to perform a true 302 with JS on the front end, I am not sure why you would want to either. If you must redirect the page/session you can use the location.assign as follows:

```
window.location.assign('https://example.com');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign

Comment: OPs method of just assigning to `.location` works just as well. But no, it definitely is not `document.location`, that can't be changed.

Comment: @Bergi Changed it to window, although the document.location is from the Mozilla example and did work within my console from another domain when I tried it. There is probably something I am missing from that part.